# How can i get a virtual machine installed on my samsung chromebook 3?

Tags: virtualbox

How can i Get a VM such as Vbox up and running on my Samsung Chromebook 3? Whenever i try to on the forums/websites, they display the same commands, but the commands never work. what should i do?

Comment: what exactly did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: i referred to this web site, i downloaded the image and executed the first command `USE=kvm ./build_image --board=lumpy --noenable_rootfs_verification --boot_args 'disablevmx=off lsm.module_locking=0'` but came up with the error `bash: ./build_image: No such file or directory`

Comment: Please [edit] your question when responding to requests for clarification.

Comment: *"... but the commands never work"* is not a useful problem statement. You should clearly state the commands and the problems or errors you encountered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**BACKUP YOUR FILES FIRST!**

Step 1: Put your Chromebook into developer mode:
https://www.howtogeek.com/210817/how-to-enable-developer-mode-on-your-chromebook/

Step 2: Download and run crouton: https://github.com/dnschneid/crouton

Step 3: Download divx118's crouton packages:
https://github.com/divx118/crouton-packages

Step 4: Download virtualbox deb and follow instructions in the video:https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads

original video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OImoN7frSdg

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.